# Positioning responsiveslides

Tags: html, css, responsive-slides

I want to position my responsiveslide and resize the image so it just fits my website. This is the current CSS file:

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  }
```

but this gives me the following result:
[image: White borders]

Is there any possible way to make the image bigger so the white borders dissapear?
Thanks.

Comment: Please make a working fiddle.  CSS is easier to debug that way.

Comment: Cant get it working in fiddle for some reason. My output: https://jsfiddle.net/z0kzgtv6/

Comment: why your `width: 90%` in `.rslides img {}`

Answer (score 2):

I used responsive slider [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) on my own projects, you can customize default CSS of slider.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.rslides img` class you have `width:90%` and `margin-left:10%` changing these to `width:100%` and `margin-left:0` (or removing the `margin-left` entirely since you already have `margin:0px`) should get rid of the white borders, and your image should stretch to fill the content

The reason I think you might have made this mistake is that you put it in both either on accident, or by confusing how the div breakdown works. In your case, the `rslides` class already moves the content by `margin-left:10%` and contains the `width:90%` so by doing it again in the `rslides img` you are effectively using 90% of 90% of the div and moving the margin by 10% of that 90% width